# * What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating settings 'project'

Tags: react-native, android-studio, gradle

when i try to import a react native project on android studio this error occured

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating settings 'project'.

> Cannot invoke method isEmpty() on null object

the line that causes this is at

```
  ..\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android

  at line 265

if (!androidConfig["buildTypes"].isEmpty()) { 
    reactNativeModulesBuildVariants.put(nameCleansed, androidConfig["buildTypes"]) 
}
```

what is the reason behind , to get tyhis error?

Comment: androidConfig["buildTypes"] is null, so you can't call a function on a null object, you need to see why androidConfig["buildTypes"] is equals to null

Comment: I am having this same issue. When I log `println androidConfig` I see there is no `["buildTypes"]` :( But still have not discovered why

Comment: @Kangzeroo did you ever figure this out? I was running into the sample problem at L265. Upgrading to @react-native-community\cli-platform-android:6.0.0 avoided this problem, but then I ran into a related issue at L275. Still stuck...

Comment: @androidnotgenius the issue was related to a library I had that did not support the node/react-native version I had. for me that library was sentry-react-native and I checked the package.json requirements. my solution was to upgrade to Node 17+

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem a few days ago.
A possible solution is to check the `package.json` file and check the compatibility between the `@react-native-community/cli` and the `react-native` packages

```
"dependencies": {
    ...

    "@react-native-community/cli": "^5.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.3"

    ...
}
```

in this example I was getting the error and fixed it by changing the react-native version to 0.64.0 and running `npm i`

On this link you can see the compatibility in documentation.
https://github.com/react-native-community/cli

if it is incompatible choose the versions according to the github documentation and run `npm i` command and test .